# Data is being written three times instead of once using requests and openpyxl?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Here is the code I am using:

```
from Sid.drivercommand import *
from Stocks.lot_size import symbol_list
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import datetime
from openpyxl import Workbook

p1_url = 'https://www.nseindia.com/marketinfo/companyTracker/mtOptionKeys.jsp?companySymbol='
p3_url = '&indexSymbol=NIFTY&series=EQ&instrument=OPTSTK&date=-'
symbol_list = ['ACC','SBIN','PNB']
loc = r"C:\Users\OneDrive\Stock Study"
loc_opt_data = r"C:\Users\OneDrive\Stock Study\Opt Data"
os.chdir(loc_opt_data)
date = 'Test_Data_'+ str(datetime.date.today()) + ".xlsx"
datewise_data = Workbook(date)
os.chdir(loc)
for symbol in symbol_list[0:1]:
    url = p1_url+symbol+p3_url
    raw_page = requests.get(url).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(raw_page, "lxml")
    if len(raw_page) > 0:
        datewise_data_sheet = datewise_data.create_sheet(symbol)

         for table in soup.findAll('table'):
             '# Fields: ' + ','.join([tr.text for tr in table.findAll('th')])
             for row in table.findAll('tr'):
                # ws1.append(([tr.text for tr in row.findAll('td')]))
                datewise_data_sheet.append(([tr.text for tr in row.findAll('td')]))
                # test.append(([tr.text for tr in row.findAll('td')]))
             #print(symbol)
        raw_page = 0
datewise_data.save(date)
```

The file generated from this has the data but each symbol has three sets of data while I only want the first set/table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have tables within tables on the web-page so your code, as it is, finds the tr elements three times as they are in the first table, an the same tr elements are in the second table and the row.findAll('td') finds them a third time as the first table td contains the second table.
You just need to find the data once so use:

```
table = soup.findAll('table')[1]
for row in table.findAll('tr'):
```

Instead of:

```
for table in soup.findAll('table'):
    for row in table.findAll('tr'):
```

This will go straight to the table within the table and give you one set of results.